# How do i solve for error str in datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, beautifulsoup, python-datetime

Goal is the use datetime to reiterate over 
http://www.harness.org.au/racing/results/?firstDate=01-01-2019
http://www.harness.org.au/racing/results/?firstDate=02-01-2019.... to yesterdays date
(should be done in `new_url = base_url + str(enddate1)`)

then once in that href, i want to circulate over meetingfulllisttable to get name and href to then get results data from each track that day.

My current error is'<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'str' - which comes from my while loop. why is this? never used datetime before

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.harness.org.au/racing/results/?firstDate="
base1_url = "http://www.harness.org.au"

webpage_response = requests.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/results/?firstDate=')

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")

format = "%d-%m-%y"
delta = timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)

yesterday1 = yesterday.strftime(format)
enddate = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
enddate1 = enddate.strftime(format)


while enddate1 <= yesterday1:
    enddate1 =+ timedelta(days=1)

    new_url = base_url + str(enddate1)
    soup12 = requests.get(new_url)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(soup12.content, "html.parser")
    table1 = soup1.find('table', class_='meetingListFull')
    for tr in table1.find_all('tr'):
        all_cells = tr.find_all('td')
        track = all_cells.a.href.get_text()
        href = all_cells.get('href')
        trackresults = base1_url + href
```

Comment: BTW, there is no such operator as `=+` - it will be misinterpreted as `enddate1 = (+ timedelta(days=1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
yesterday1 = yesterday.strftime(format)
```

Is a string. That's why you are getting that error

Comment: The problem is that as you enter the while loop both `enddate1` and yesterday1 are strings then you are assigning `enddate1` to  `timedelta(days=1)` (not sure why). So you need to decide whether you want to do comparisons between datetime objects or strings.

Comment: And also as @Błotosmętek pointed out, there is no such operator as `=+`. I'm guessing you wanted to use `+=` operator to increment `enddate1` by 1 day?

Comment: As I said,calling `strftime(format)` on a `datetime` object gives you a string. You wouldn't be able to increment a string using `timedelta`. You should have just used `yesterday` and `enddate` really. Also worth checking the documentation of the library you're working with if you are not sure what a method does.